# DB with multiple foreign keys linked to same Model on differents attributes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, model, foreign-keys

I am having difficulties building my DB relation, if anyone could give me a little help i would greatly appreciate!

I have one table named **Person** and another one called **Company** and **Company has many Persons** and **Person belongs_to Company**

Here the trick Company has_many Person threw an **attribute called person** and has_many Person threw another **attribute called administrator**

Could be see  like

```
Coca-cola = Company.new
jonathan = Person.new / nicolas = Person.new
Coca-cola : { 
person: jonathan,nicolas
administrator: nicolas
}
```

I did that first migration :

```
def change
 add_reference :persons, :person, index: true
 add_reference :persons, :administrator, index: true

 add_foreign_key :persons, :companys, column: :person_id
 add_foreign_key :persons, :companys, column: :administrator_id
end
```

then I added this relation to my model

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many      :persons,
  :class_name => "Person",
  :foreign_key  => "person_id"

  has_many      :administrators,
  :class_name => "Person",
  :foreign_key  => "administrator_id"
end
```

and

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to    :person,
  :class_name => "Company",
  optional: true

  belongs_to    :administrator,
  :class_name => "Company",
  optional: true
end
```

And unfortunately that doesnt working, any lead on what could cause the problem ?

Thanks a lots.

Jonathan.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if I understood your problem. Requirements are:

- Person belongs_to Company
- Company has_many Persons
- Company has_many Administrators

I guess you could solve with the following code:

```
class ChangePersons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :persons, :administrator, :boolean, default: false
  end
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :persons, -> { where(administrator: false) }

  has_many :administrators,
    class_name: "Person",
    foreign_key: "person_id",
    -> { where(administrator: true) }
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Comment: Thanks you Gabriel for your answer, yes it is one of the option that i considered but in the futur they might have other has_many with other type of person for example :employee or other stuff.